# Create custom measure by adding new event attribute

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to ask if there is possible to add custom Event Attributes under Measure (i.e. Email Studio -> Subscribers -> Measures)? I couldn't find any option there. thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make anything custom from Measures Job or Event Attributes. These are created via the Data View and SOAP Objects that exist 'behind the curtain' and are readable, but not editable or creatable. You could try talking to Salesforce Support to see if they have any options, but likely they will push you instead to custom reports or solutions which are expensive.

On that note, I would highly recommend moving away from Measures and instead focusing on SQL Query Activities. Although there is a technical knowledge requirement, they are much more powerful and also more efficient and accurate.

I have found that due to the Measures only being refreshed periodically, that depending on when you run it, it can be inaccurate and cause you to make decisions on incorrect data. Even without that, I have found times that the returned results do not match a SQL Query pulling the exact same info.  Since then I have complete distrust of Measures and usually recommend not to use them.